# Laravel Eloquent ORM relations for tables that are linked by a mutual table

Tags: eloquent, foreign-keys, relational-database, relationship, laravel-10

I have two tables size_variations and sub_categories, these tables are linked through another table that has both of their ids as foreign key.

All the solutions I can find are those in which there is a deeper relation `table_1` id is foreign key of `table_2` and `table_2`  id is foreign key of `table_3`

**Tables Structure**

`sub_categories`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | gloss enamel |
| 2 | matt enamel |
| 2 | weather coat |

`size_variations`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | drum |
| 2 | gallon |
| 3 | quarter |

`sub_category_size_variation_relations`

| id | sub_category_id | size_varaition_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 |

Now as I'm getting sub categories data I want get size variations data related to that sub category

the relation in `SizeVariation` Model is

```
class SizeVariation extends Model

{

    use HasFactory;


    public function sizeVartionRelation()
   {
        return $this->hasMany(SubCategorySizeVariationRelation::class);
   }
}
```

the relation in `SubCategorySizeVariationRelation` Model is

```
class SubCategorySizeVariationRelation extends Model

{

    use HasFactory;


    public function subcategory()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(SubCategory::class, 'sub_category_id', 'id');
    }

    public function sizevariation()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(SizeVariation::class, 'size_variation_id', 'id');
   }
}
```

So for this in SubCategory Model I had hasMany relation to SubCategorySizeVariationRelation

```
public function sizeVariationIds()

{
    return $this->hasMany(SubCategorySizeVariationRelation::class);
}
```

and this worked so than I used `hasManyThrough`

Now I'm stuck at how can I get the size variations data, what kind of relation will I've to make? I tried

```
public function sizeVariations()

{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(SizeVariation::class, SubCategorySizeVariationRelation::class,'size_variation_id', 'id');
}
```

**The Query is as following**

```
public function index(){
    $sub_categories = SubCategory::with('category:id,name')->with('sizeVariations')->get();
    
    return Inertia::render('SubCategories/Index', ['subCategories' => $sub_categories]);
}
```

I'm getting back an size_variations array but its empty in SubCategory array.